# why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^c \tau_n(x)dx \int_0^d \overline{\tau_n(x)}dx$ is the $min(c,d)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Let $\{ \tau_n (x) \}_{n=1}^\infty$ be closed orthonormal system in $L^2_{pc}[0,1]$ show that for $c,d\in (0,1)$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^c \tau_n(x)dx \int_0^d \overline{\tau_n(x)}dx = min\{c,d\}$$

Comment: What is $L^2_{pc}$? Piecewise continuous or constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the characteristic functions of the intervals $\chi_d : = \chi_{[0,d]}, \chi_C := \chi_{[0,c]}$. Then, we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^c \tau_n(x)dx \int_0^d \overline{\tau_n(x)}dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \tau_n(x) \chi_d(x) dx \int_0^1 \overline{\tau_n(x)}\chi_c(x)dx$$
Notice now that for any $f,g$ in $L^2$ we have:

$$
\langle f,g \rangle = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \langle f, e_n \rangle \langle g , e_n \rangle$$

In particular it follows:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \int_0^1 \tau_n(x) \chi_d(x) dx \int_0^1 \overline{\tau_n(x)}\chi_c(x)dx \right] = \int_0^1 \chi_c(x) \chi_d(x)dx = \min(c,d)
$$
as the left hand side above is the right hand side two lines above, and vice versa